# How to create an HtmlSelectOneMenu at runtime using MyFaces 1.1.5

Tags: jsf, binding, runtime, myfaces, selectonemenu

Im using myfaces-api-1.1.5.jar. (sadly, can't use anything other than this!)

I want to create the following at run time (ie. dynamically) from my backing bean, testBB.

```
<t:selectOneMenu 
    value="#{testBB.someVO}"
    converter="someVOConverter"
    valueChangeListener="#{testBB.vcl}"
    onchange="submit();" style="width:170px">

    <f:selectItems value="#{testBB.selectItemList}"/>
</t:selectOneMenu>
```

My code so far is as follows:

```
private UIComponent createComponent(
    String id, String componentType, UIComponent parent) {

    if (componentType == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("argument 'componentType' is null");
    }

    if (parent == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("argument 'parent' is null");
    }

    UIComponent newComponent = this.
        getApplication().createComponent(componentType);
    newComponent.setId(id);
    newComponent.setParent(parent);
    parent.getChildren().add(newComponent);
    logger.debug("new Component created.. ");

    return newComponent;
}

private HtmlSelectOneMenu createSelectOneMenu(
    String id, UIComponent parent, String expr) {
    HtmlSelectOneMenu selectOneMenu = 
        (HtmlSelectOneMenu) this.createComponent(id, 
        HtmlSelectOneMenu.COMPONENT_TYPE, parent);
    UISelectItems items = (UISelectItems)this.
        createComponent("selectItem", UISelectItems.COMPONENT_TYPE, selectOneMenu);
    ValueBinding valueBinding = this.getApplication().createValueBinding(expr);
    items.setValueBinding(id, valueBinding);

    return selectOneMenu;
}
```

And I call it using:

```
this.createSelectOneMenu("someId", "somePanelGrid", "#{testBB.selectItemList}");
```

I tried Googleand searched StackOverflow but couldn't find anything specific to MyFaces and JSF 1.1.

All help will be greatly appreciated.